# Android 7.x opengl TextureView and locking screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, textureview

I have an Android app that uses the TextureView component with opengl content.

On previous versions of Android this works fine, but on Android 7.0 and above it appears that if I am displaying content but then lock the screen and unlock the opengl content disappears and screen is blank. If I tap the screen content returns.

Just wondering if anyone has seen similar issues or knows what I might be doing wrong. I'd post sample code but like I said this is working fine up till Android 7.0 so it has to be something that has changed there.

Certainly my code my be misbehaving but trying to find out what might be different on newer versions.

Comment: I have encountered this problem. I can't find a solution at the moment. Are you playing a video? If so, you can circumvent it in other ways. Textureview can get the bitmap, and then overwrite an imageview in the playback screen to block the blacked out par